# Two pointers not deleted properly

Tags: c++, pointers

so basically I'm trying this code out, compiling in cl (visual studio C++ compiler) and it keeps printing 0. Shouldn't y be equal to nullptr?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int* x;
    x = new int(5);
    int* y;
        y = x;
    delete x;
    x = nullptr;
    cout <<(y==nullptr)<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have two different variables, each containing a *copy* of each other (initially). It's like having e.g. `int x = 5; int y = x; x = 0;` and then wondering why `y` is not equal to `0` as well?

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting. This is well-written with a compilable example. Please don't downvote on the grounds of obviousness.

Comment: how do I check if y is pointing to corrupt memory before deleting it?

Comment: @JukesOnYou: You can't. That's why we have nice things like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: You'll be less confused if you remember that you aren't deleting the *pointers*, but rather what is being pointed at, the *pointee*.

Comment: @JukesOnYou How do you check if `y` is corrupt? There's no built in way of doing that. Welcome to C++. You need to code in a way that everything you allocate (with `new`) gets deallocated exactly once (with `delete`). It's easier than you might think but takes discipline. Setting things to `nullptr` after delete is a valid technique but far from all the answer. Also if C++11+ use `std::unique_ptr<>` and `std::shared_ptr<>` and if not other ownership semantics and RAII

Comment: @StoryTeller: That's a nice way of putting it. I will upvote that if you elevate that nugget out of the quagmire of the comments into a gleaming answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba - Appreciate it. But I don't think it has any value on its own. It's only meaningful when paired with something like your answer. And I don't see a point re-iterating what was already well said. You can nab it and add to your answer if you wish :)

Answer (score 5):

No, setting `x` to `nullptr` does not set `y` to `nullptr` too.

`y` is an `int*` not a *reference* to an `int*`.

So, `y == nullptr` is necessarily<sup>1</sup> `false`.

---

<sup>1</sup> For the pub quiz: `x` **cannot** be `nullptr` since if an allocation failed then `std::bad_alloc` would have been thrown. It *would* be possible for `y` to be `nullptr` had you written `x = new(std::nothrow) int(5);`

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is not "deleted". The delete operation deallocates the memory block pointed to by the pointer, and leaves this pointer unchanged. It is not set to `nullptr`, and does not point to "nothing" (by the way, you are clearing it explicitly).

And a pointer behaves like an ordinary variable, holding a value (an address). Changing the value of a variable doesn't influence another (except in case of aliasing, but that's another story.)

Comment: *"and leaves this pointer unchanged."* - That's subject to interpretation. After the operation, the pointer value is officially invalid. And that opens an entire avenue of implementation defined shenanigans that the standard is perfectly okay with.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I can't follow you at all. If before the delete the pointer holds 0x43FF4500, after the delete it still holds 0x43FF4500, full stop. You are making the same mistake as the OP, believing that there is a voodoo relation between the pointer variable and the block of memory it once pointed to. For instance, it would be harmless to copy the "officially invalid" pointer value to another pointer.

Comment: That's rich. I suggest you actually read about addrees invalidation, what it means as far as implementation defined behavior is concerned, and how even your assumption that `x==y` immediatley following the delete expresion is not mandated by the standard.

Comment: @StoryTeller: you are right, copying the value is UB.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are still normal variables, with a right and a left value.

They are special only in the fact that their right value is an address of a memory location that can be managed by the user.

In your case, both `x` an `y` are allocated somewhere on the stack. Where you do `y=x` you set the value of `y` to be the same value of `x`, but later, when you do `x=nullptr` you only change the value of `x`, not the value of `y`.

Also, pay attention to the fact that while before `delete x` both `x` and `y` refer to a valid address, after it `x` is correctly set to a `nullptr`, while `y` retains the now invalid memory address. This is a case of [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), which can give several problems, first of all invalid memory access errors.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Let's go line by line:

```
x = new int(5); //allocate an integer, set it to 5 and return a pointer to it (x will not nullptr).
int* y; //allocate local storage to another pointer.
y = x; //copy the (not nullptr) value of x into y.
delete x; //de-allocate the space previously allocated.
//At this point the value of x is unchanged and y is equal to it.
//De-referencing x (*x) however is undefined because it was deallocated.
x = nullptr; //Set x to nullptr. Has no effect on y.
cout <<(y==nullptr)<< endl; //y still equals the (now invalid) value allocated above.
```

Assigning a variable to another variable is one-time thing. After that changes to one will not be reflected in the other (though changes 'through' one may affect the other).

Answer (score 0):

What actually is happening here:

1. You declare a new pointer of type int as x.
2. You point x to a new int.
3. You declare a new pointer as y.
4. You assign the value of x to value of y, that is y points to the new int as well now.
5. You delete x.
6. You print the result of a conditional operation that checks wether y is equal to nullptr, which is false as y is still pointing to the int and has some value. Thus, the result prints out to be 0, i.e., false.
7. You return 0! :P